# How to customize custom taxonomy url?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, urls

I have a Custom Post type "Data" with a custom Taxonomy "data-category".

Currently my site url when I visit a 'data-category' shows like this :

www.mysite.com/data-category/home-loan

Here **Home-Loan** is a child of **Personal Loan** data-category.

I need my url to show like this :

www.mysite.com/personal-loan/home-loan

Yes I need to get rid of 'data-category' from my url.

Thanks

Comment: You can use this plugin: [Remove Taxonomy Base Slug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/).

Comment: Try this, http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/remove-the-slug-from-your-custom-post-type-permalinks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. By default wordpress doesn't show hierarchical URL for custom taxonomies.

Therefore while registering custom taxonomy, we must include the rewrite variable.

```
 $args = array(

        'rewrite'           => array( 'hierarchical' => true ),

    );
```

Comment: Still One problem remains though. I can't have same slug for different category childs.

www.mysite.com/Personal/home-loan
www.mysite.com/leasing/home-loan

It is not possible as 'home-loan' slug can't be use twice. Looking to resolve it.